# Clarify on the text of an exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $I\subseteq A$ an ideal. Define $R$ the subring of $A\times A$ consisting of the pairs $(a,b)$ for which $a-b\in I$. Assume that $I$ is non-zero and doesn't contain any irreducible component of $\operatorname{Spec}A$, and that $A$ is integrally closed. Show that $R$ is not integrally closed and find its integral closure.

This is from a paper of exercises of my course; I'm not looking for a solution, just to have some clarifies.

First: is it necessary to assume that $I$ is non-zero if there is the other hypothesis, equivalent to $I$ not being contained in any minimal prime? As $0$ is contained in any ideal, in particular any minimal prime, I would say that $I$ is automatically non-zero.

Second: talking about the integral closure of a ring only makes sense when the ring is a domain (right?); however even if we assume that $A$ is a domain, for a non-zero $i\in I$, the pairs $(i,0),(0,i)\in R$ are zero-divisors.

Is the exercise invalid or it's me not understanding? Thank you

Comment: If you're in a course, doesn't that mean that you have a professor or instructor you can ask for clarification on things like this? I think they'd be glad to help you out with these sorts of questions about whether the exercise is set up correctly.